# Issue : Passing ArrayList between intents loses data

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I am passing custom `ArrayList` in `putParcelableArrayListExtra`, but when I receive it within `onCreate` method of other class, then some values of array are `null`

```
put...   get...

[a]  ->  [a]

[b]  ->  null

[c]  ->  [b]

[d]  ->  null

[e]  ->  [c]
```

I am sending data in  `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(key, value);` and getting it as `arrayList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(key));`

Kindly suggest how to solve this issue.

Comment: Without any parcelable code implementation it's anyones guess. What about sharing the necessary code...??? Try using http://www.parcelabler.com/ for generating the parcelable code and paste it inside your object.

Comment: Post your code of how you implement parcelable interface if it is an ArrayList of Object.

Answer (score 0):

make all the classes that are used Parecelable. Then override `writeToParcel` and create `public static final Parcelable.Creator<YourClass>` to read from parcel and create an object from your object.

But the simplest will be to use `Serializable` interface. reading and writing will be automatically handled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a pojo/setter getter class with the implementation of **Parcelable** .

   ```
   public class MyData implements Parcelable
   ```
2. Declare the values in your pojo which will be an arraylist item

   ```
   MyData data = new MyData("id", "text");
   ```
3. Call the parcelable method from the intent with your another activity.

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("key", data);
   startActivity(i);
   ```
4. Get the list with parcelable method of that class intent,

   ```
   MyData data = i.getExtras().getParcelable("key");
   List<MyData> mList = new ArrayList<>();
   mList.add(data);
   ```